# Parse INI-file inside .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ini

How can I parse a ini-file within .htaccess? In my case .htaccess placed in the root directory (/) and target ini-file is /conf/params.ini.

Comment: What are you trying to configure using `/conf/params.ini`?

Comment: I want read some parameters affecting mod_deflate behaviour (switch on/off, compression level). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can control [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) behaviour directly in the `.htaccess` file as it's an Apache function and not PHP. `php.ini` can be modified directly if required or you can change settings from within scripts, but this doesn't sound like your intention.

A similar mod_deflate issue here, where some fairly advanced setting are being used: [Mod_deflate and mod_header settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262163/mod-deflate-and-mod-header-settings)

Comment: I decided to use PHP for files compression, because of I dont see a way to read settings from third-party files through .htaccess...

Comment: Thats a fair choice - There are usually many ways to achieve compression! Good luck.